# Progress bar not working when autoProcessQueue is false

Tags: dropzone.js

I'm using Dropzone.js to display image on my site.

It is working wonderfully, but there is one problem.

After I realized that Dropzone automatically sends image information without user pressing submit button, I set autoProcessQueue to false.

Now, it doesn't send the information automatically, but progress bar is broken as seen in the picture below.

[image]

There seems to be a white line on the image and it doesn't look good.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with the progress bar. I'm using twitter-bootstrap and jQuery in my solution as well. This solution with the progress bar works fine for me (see element with id `total-progress`).

This is my template:

```
<!-- Upload preview template begin -->
<div id="preview-template" style="display: none;">
    <div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview" style="display:inline-block;margin:10px;">
        <div class="dz-details">
            <div class="dz-filename label label-primary">
                <span data-dz-name></span>
            </div>
            <br style="line-height:2px;" />
            <div class="dz-error-message label label-danger" style="display:none;clear:both;">
                <span data-dz-errormessage></span>
            </div>
            <br style="line-height:2px;" />
            <!--<div class="dz-size" data-dz-size></div>-->
            <img data-dz-thumbnail style="border-radius:5px;clear:both;" />
        </div>
        <!--<div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>-->
        <!-- <div class="dz-success-mark"><span>?</span></div> -->
        <!-- <div class="dz-error-mark"><span>?</span></div> -->
        <div data-dz-remove class="btn btn-default removePicFromAlbum" title="Entfernen"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove center-block" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
        <div id="total-progress" class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0" style="width:100px;">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;" data-dz-uploadprogress></div>
        </div>
        <!--<img src="removebutton.png" alt="Click me to remove the file." data-dz-remove />-->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Upload preview template end -->
```

And here is my Javascript code:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var {{$name or 'upload'}} = new Dropzone("div#{{$name or 'upload'}}", {
    url: "{{ action("$controllerClass@store") }}"
    , method: "post"
    , paramName: "file" // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    , maxFilesize: {{$maxFilesize or str_replace('M','',ini_get('upload_max_filesize')) }} // MB
    , uploadMultiple: false
    , dictDefaultMessage: "{{$text or 'Ziehen Sie Dateien in diesen Bereich, um diese hochzuladen'}}"
    , previewTemplate: document.getElementById('preview-template').innerHTML
    //, acceptedFiles:'image/*'
    , previewsContainer: '#logoPreview'
    , thumbnailWidth: {{$thumbnailWidth or 100}}
    , thumbnailHeight: {{$thumbnailHeight or 100}}
    , sending: function (file, xhr, formData) {
        formData.append('_token', '{!!csrf_token() !!}');
    }
    , success: function(file, responseText) {
        if(responseText != undefined) {
            if (responseText.success != undefined && responseText.success == "false") {
                $(file.previewElement).find('.dz-error-message').text("Fehler: " + responseText.errorMessage);
                $(file.previewElement).find('.dz-error-message').css('display','inline-block');
            }
            else {
                $(file.previewElement).find('.dz-error-message').css('display','none');
            }
        }
        $(file.previewElement).find('#total-progress').css('display','none');
    }
    , error: function(file, message, xhr) {
        var header = "Error " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText;
        $(file.previewElement).find('.dz-error-message').text(header);
        $(file.previewElement).find('.dz-error-message').css('display','inline-block');
        $(file.previewElement).find('#total-progress').css('display','none');
    }
    , uploadProgress: function(progress) {
        document.querySelector("#total-progress .progress-bar").style.width = progress + "%";
    }
    , completed: function(progress) {
        $(file.previewElement).find('#total-progress').css('display','none');
    }
    , removedfile: function(file) {
        removeFile(file.name);
        $(file.previewElement).remove();
    }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You binded progress bar to wrong event. Replace `uploadProgress` by `uploadprogress`.

Doc is here: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-uploadprogress

Comment: If `autoProcessQueue to false` then uploadprogress should be [totaluploadprogress](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-totaluploadprogress)

Answer (score 0):

This post may be old but I got easy answer. So I am posting here for anyone who needs help on this.

Remove autoProcessQueue: false  and set url: "#". When you set the url: "#", then dropzone can't process automatically but autoProcessQueue: true (by default) will help to trigger animation

This way, it worked for me

```
Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                url: "#",
                init: function () {

                }
            };
```